# Python unittest change mock patch value on fly

Tags: python, django, pymongo, python-unittest

I'm having trouble while dealing with patching. I'm using mock from unittest library. While testing check_codes() view I would like to set another values to db.find_one()

api.utils.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os

def get_share_code_collection():
    client = MongoClient(os.getenv("DB_HOST"))
    db_handle = client[os.getenv("DB_NAME")]
    return db_handle["share_codes"]
```

views.py

```
def check_codes(self, request):
    db = get_share_code_collection()
    data = db.find_one({"specialist_id": {"$exists": True}})
```

test_views.py

```
 from unittest import mock
 @mock.patch("api.utils.get_share_code_collection")
 def test_share_code_correct_no_share_types(
     self, mocked_collection, mocked_share_code, user_model
 ):
     mocked_collection().find_one.return_value = True
     ...

 @mock.patch("api.utils.get_share_code_collection")
 def test_share_code_no_start_time(
     self, mocked_collection, user_model
 ):
    mocked_collection().find_one.return_value = False
     ...
```

The only workaround I found is setting

```
mocked_collection().find_one.side_effect = [True,False]
```

but once it is initialized I can't add values. How can I deal with the problem?

Comment: you can also assign a function to `.side_effect` in this you could query a global variable. It feels like bad practice though. Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Yes I thought about it and I am looking for some better resolution. Splitting tests with modules also doesn't help. I am testing views which use pymongo to connect to mongodb and I need to mock queries result. Do you know any another approach ?

Comment: tbh I just gave up trying to mock mongodb and just run tests with a local dev db